# Add Attribute Pricing column to Woocommerce product Admin

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, admin

I'm trying to customize the Woocommerce Products columns by adding the Pricing of the Attributes on Variable products.

The site uses WPML and the products have the ability to add multiple currencies within each variation as shown in this image: [admin image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A86x1.png)

We are using two currencies for each product variation and need this to show up in the Woo Products page in the Admin so that we can be sure that we have entered the correct pricing per variation per product without having to individually open up each product one by one, which would take weeks.

For instance, we want a column label of "USD" that would display all of the prices for each size variation (small, medium, large, XL), and then another column label of "THB" that would show the prices of the second currency for the same variations. Here is a mockup version to visually display what I mean: [mockup image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYQzq.png)

I found this snippet below on stackoverflow to display a column, but don't know how to find the data to get the variations prices to display. 
If someone could help me out I would so appreciate it.

Thanks,
Dan

```js
// ADDING A CUSTOM COLUMN TITLE TO ADMIN PRODUCTS LIST
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'custom_product_column',11);
function custom_product_column($columns)
{
   //add columns
   $columns['attribute'] = __( 'Attribute','woocommerce'); // title
   return $columns;
}

// ADDING THE DATA FOR EACH PRODUCTS BY COLUMN (EXAMPLE)
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_product_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_list_column_content( $column, $product_id )
{
    global $post;

    // HERE get the data from your custom field (set the correct meta key below)
    $variable_regular_price_0 = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_variable_regular_price_0', true );

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'delivery' :
            echo $variable_regular_price_0; // display the data
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I click "Inspect" on one of the "Regular Price (THB)" fields I get this code: `<input type="text" name="_custom_variation_regular_price[THB][16489]" class="wc_input_price wcml_input_price short wcml_regular_price" value="1390.0" step="any" min="0">`

Comment: Did you find any solution?